# How to use a escaping closure in a func to return some data?

Tags: ios, swift, closures, swift5

In my Code,I want to return some data in a fun after a network request.

```
    func funcName()->String{
        var data = "demo"
        DataLoader.fetch { result in
            if case .success(let fetchedData) = result {
                data = fetchedData
            } else {
                data = "Fail"
            }
        }
        return data
    }
```

The DataLoader is used to get some data from API, the code just like:

```
struct DataLoader {
    static func fetch(completion: @escaping (Result<String, Error>) -> Void) {
        let url = URL(string: "URL LINK")!
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                completion(.failure(error!))
                return
            }
            completion(.success(data!))
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

But as you know `data` will always be `"demo"` because of `escaping closure`.

So how can I return the data after the network request complete without modify the function `funcName`'s params?

**If the parameters of the function are not modified.**

> I'm new in swift, and really at a loss.Thanks a lot if you could help me out!

Comment: "But as you know data will always be "demo" because escaping closure".. data will be demo becuase it will return the value before the network request has completed and the closure called.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning data from async call in Swift function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203556/returning-data-from-async-call-in-swift-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to modify the `funcName` also to completion `closure`, instead of `return`.

```
func funcName(completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
    var data = "demo"
    DataLoader.fetch { result in
        if case .success(let fetchedData) = result {
            data = fetchedData
        } else {
            data = "Fail"
        }
        completion(data)
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
funcName { name in
    print(name)
}
```

Comment: You need to make comletion @escaping also

Comment: Oops! Thanks mate.

Comment: Yeah,I know it, but I just want to keep `funcName`'s params to make it as the function is  a override function.

Comment: Explain what you mean by "I just want to keep funcName's params to make it as the function is a override function" in your question.

Comment: If the parameters of the function are not modified.